# Tips for using vimtex?

Tags: plugin-vimtex

I am a new user to [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex). Here are some requests for tips.

- I hear that it has "make on write" feature. How do I enable it to use my flags to `makelatex`, so that it uses e.g., `lualatex`.
- Which keybindings do you have for useful features, e.g., find next error/warning?
- How do you enable/use the F7 key mentioned in the documentation?

Comment: One question per post, please.

Comment: This should instead have been opened as an issue for vimtex, although the latter two questions are answered in the documentation. To use `lualatex`, you only need to configure your `.latexmkrc` correctly.